# Отправка почты со вложениями на php

Tags: email, php, sendmail

Здраствуйте.
Есть функция, написанная на php для отправки почты с приложенными файлами. Вот она:

```
 function send_mail($to, $from, $subj, $text, $files = null, $isHTML = false){
        $boundary = "--".strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand())));
        $headers  = "From: ".$from."\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=\"$boundary\"\n";
        if (!$isHTML){
            $type = 'text/plain';
        }else{
            $type = 'text/html';

            }
            //  echo "BODY: :".$text;
            $body =  $boundary."\nContent-Type: ".$type."; charset=utf-8\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: Quot-Printed\n\n".$text."\n\n";

            if ((is_array($files))&&(!empty($files))){
                foreach($files as $filename => $filecontent){
                    if(strlen($filename)>0 && $filecontent)
                    $body .= $boundary."\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream; file_name = \"".$filename."\"\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename = \"".$filename."\"\n\n".chunk_split(base64_encode($filecontent))."\n";
                    echo "\nBODY: ".$body;
                    }
            }

            return mail($to, $subj, $body, $headers);

            }
```

Нече в ней замудренного нет, но вот почему-то полученное письмо нормально не отображается. Например если я пишу:

```
$files = array('123.txt' => file_get_contents('[full_path_to_file]/123.txt'));
$send = kmail ("xxx@mail.ru", "someemail@server.com", "Test", "Just a test. Without russian characters", $files);
```

Мне приходит сообщение со следующими заголовками:

```
 Date: Fri, 6 May 2011 00:14:58 +0700 (NOVST)
    Message-Id: <201105051714.p45HEwCW041315@server.com>
    To: xxx@mail.ru
    Subject: TEst
    X-PHP-Originating-Script: 2001:send.php
    From: someemail@server.com
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary="--563EB809F4CD1C783E4CAFFA3C2812F3"
    X-Spam: Not detected
    X-Mras: OK

    ----563EB809F4CD1C783E4CAFFA3C2812F3--
```

А все остальное в одном единственном вложенном файле с неизвестно каким названием:

```
 --D08148968BCC11D17FACF1AA4E004C9A
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quot-Printed

    Just a test. Without russian characters

    --D08148968BCC11D17FACF1AA4E004C9A
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream; file_name = "123.txt"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = "123.txt"

    MTIzMjEzMTIzMTIzMTIzMTIzMTIzMTIzZWRhc2RzZGZzZGFmc2Fmc2FkZndlZnNkZHZjeGN6dnpz
    ZHY=

    ----D08148968BCC11D17FACF1AA4E004C9A--
```

Т.е. как бы письмо приходит полностью, только криво воспринимается почтовым клиентом... 
В чем может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы вместе с вложением, приходил текст сообщения, у меня пока-что всё пусто, но файл прикреплён нормально.
???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

boundary в хиадере должно быть без "--" а внутри письма ( разделение частей ) уже с "--"

В остальном, беглым взглядом вроде всё нормально.

PS: не так важно, но желательно, используйте \r\n вместо \n

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ И ПРЕОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО! ) Это помогло!

Comment: Кстати насчет \r\n на  написали, что лучше использовать \n:
I have found out when developing a function sending a text/html multipart message that multiple headers are better separated by \n instead of \r\n. I have used \r\n only in te last one. This was done to ensure cross-platform consistency of the e-mail. There atr some mail systems interpreting \r\n as the end of the headers and the start of the message body.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php

Comment: Поэтому и сделал \n...

Answer (score 3):

К слову. Когда-то делал похожую функцию и наткнулся на печальный факт - разные почтовые сервисы и почтовые клиенты имеют свое собственное понятие о том, что такое правильный почтовый формат, особенно это качалось аттачмента и встроенных в письмо картинок. 
mail.ru и gmail.com очень сильно отличались в этом смысле. Соответственно Thebat "дружил" с mail.ru, а Thunderbird, Outlook - с гугловой почтой. Так что конкретные реализации конструктора писем могут быть "заточены" под разные сервисы, это стоит иметь ввиду.